# How to define the pathway of particular events in each session in the app in Bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have a data from the events section in Firebase exported as raw data in Bigquery.

I figured out how to do the query for each unique user, but there is a problem with session. Now the client wants to see different sessions of each user: when does he enter the application and when does he finishes. I have all the events already in my data. I only need the code.

Hopefully you understand. Waiting for your answers

I tried this:

```
SELECT countif(event_1 = "first_open") AS funnel_1_count, 
  countif(event_1 = "first_open" AND event_2 = 
    "auth") AS funnel_2_count,
  countif(event_1 = "first_open" AND event_2 = 
    "auth" AND event_3 = "cat_list") AS 
    funnel_3_count,
    countif(event_1="first_open" AND event_2 = "auth" and event_3="cat_list" and event_4="amulet_screen") AS
    funnel_4_count
FROM 
(
  SELECT event_name as event_1,
    LEAD(event_name, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY 
      event_timestamp) AS event_2,
    LEAD(event_name, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY 
      event_timestamp) AS event_3,
    LEAD(event_name, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY 
      event_timestamp) AS event_4,
    user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp
  FROM
  (
    SELECT event_name, user_pseudo_id , event_timestamp,
      LEAD (event_name, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER 
        BY event_timestamp) AS next_event
    FROM `weawe-app.analytics_218516825.events_20200204`
    WHERE event_name IN ("first_open", "auth", 
      "cat_list", "amulet_screen")
    ORDER BY 2,3,4
  ) 
  WHERE event_name != next_event OR next_event IS NULL
)
```

Comment: I need to know which event is the first in the session's pathway out of my 20 listed particular events

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you struggling?

Comment: I tried this - edited. I am struggling over counting events by sessions not by users